# Links size down in mobile view

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on making an online portfolio of some of my poems that has an ebook-inspired layout. I have a weird problem in mobile view I can't seem to quite fix. On the "Acknowledgements" page, link text is smaller than regular text. I am using ID tags with these links so that they're formatted differently (titles are italic, publications are bold). Adding this bit to the header makes all of the text the same size:

```
<style>

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

</style>
```

The problem is that then the entire page displays smaller than I'd like it to, and I think it's harder to read on a screen.

The other thing that I realized is that there might be a problem with all of the links, but these are the only ones that are noticeable since they're embedded with regular text (while the others are not). I've tried everything I can think of and can't fix it, but this is also my first time using the @media tags, so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Any ideas as to what's causing this? Here's [a live link](http://stephanielanesutton.com/poems/acknowledgements.html) to the page so you might be able to see what I'm talking about, and I'm including some code below.

Here's the CSS:

```
    /* color reference

  lilac - #D8BFD8
  dark gray - #74756a

*/




/* cover */

#moon {

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 30px 15px 3px 0 #D8BFD8;
}



#title {
      font-family: "Geo";
    font-size: 92px;
    color: #74756a;
    letter-spacing: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 1px rgba(255,0,255,0.5) , 0px 0 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.5) ;
    display: inline-block;

}

#by {
    font-family: "Geo";
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #74756a;
    /* font-weight: lighter; */
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    text-transform: none;

        /*taller*/
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scaleY(1.1);  
}

.button {
  font-family: "Geo";
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #D8BFD8;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button a {
  font-family: "Geo";
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #D8BFD8;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
}


.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


.splash {background: linear-gradient(266deg, #4e0846, #9f8c98, #d8d8bf, #ffffff);
background-size: 800% 800%;

-webkit-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
-moz-animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;
animation: AnimationName 30s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 51%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes AnimationName {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 51%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes AnimationName { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 51%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}

/* Body Fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: Geo;
    src: url(geo.ttf);
}

body {
    font-size: 18px;
}

p {
  font-family: "Geo";

  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30em;

}





/* TOC, Coming Soon & Acknowledgements */

p#contents {
  font-family: "Geo";
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 40%;
  width: 100em;

}



a#ack {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Geo";
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #74756a;

}

a#ack:hover {
   color: #D8BFD8;
}

}

#low {

  font-family: "Geo";
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 30em;
}

a#soon {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #74756a;
    padding: 0;
}

 a#soon:hover {
    color: #D8BFD8;
}





/* headers */

h1 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Geo";
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #74756a;
    /* font-weight: lighter; */
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-shadow: -2px 0 1px rgba(255,0,255,0.5) , 0px 0 1px rgba(155,155,155,0.5) ;

        /*taller*/
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scaleY(1.1);


}

h2 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Geo";

    color: #74756a;
    font-weight: lighter; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;

}


h3 {
    display: inline;
    font-family: "Geo";
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #74756a;
    font-weight: lighter; 
    letter-spacing: 3px;


}


h4{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Geo";

  color: #74756a;
}

/* Arrows */

#left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 5%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-5%) translateY(-50%);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Geo";
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #74756a;
}

a:hover {
    color: #D8BFD8;

}


}

.round {
    border-radius: 50%;
}


/* Social Media Icons */

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

#menu-outer {
  height: 25px;
  background: url(images/bar-bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}

.table {
  display: table;   /* Allow the centering to work */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#social-media-list{
  min-width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  }

ul#social-media-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#social-media-list a:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #D8BFD8;
  border-right: 5px solid #D8BFD8;
}




/*Formal Anomolies<*/

.jty {

      text-align: justify;
      text-indent: 0;
  font-family: "Geo";


}


.ery {

  font-family: "Geo";

  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 35%;

}


/*mobile*/

@media (min-width: 858px) {
    html {
        font-size: 12px;
    }


}

@media (min-width: 780px) {
    html {
        font-size: 11px;
    }


}

@media (min-width: 702px) {
    html {
        font-size: 10px;
    }


}

@media (min-width: 724px) {
    html {
        font-size: 9px;
    }


}

@media (max-width: 623px) {
    html {
        font-size: 8px;
    }



}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Stephanie Lane Sutton | Acknowledgements</title>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.50, maximum-scale=3, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ebook.css" type="text/css">

<!DOCTYPE html 
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="flwr.png">


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>

<style>

    body {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<center><h3>Acknowledgements</h3>
</center>
<p><br>
Thanks to the following publications which first published these poems: 

<br><br><br>
<a href="murmuration.html" id="ack">Murmuration</a> and <a href="spit.html" id="ack">Spit</a> were originally published in <a href="http://arseniclobster.magere.com/archive/issuefortyone/index.html" id="soon">Arsenic Lobster</a>. <br><br>

<a href="hyperv.html" id="ack">Hypervigilance (w/ Emily Dickinson)</a> was originally published in <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FDWVIHO" rel="nofollow noreferrer" id="soon">Day One</a>. <br><br>

<a href="death.html" id="ack">Death Visits as Often as a Distant Relative</a> was originally published in <a href="http://districtlit.com/post/112434612956/sutton" id="soon">District Lit</a>.<br><br>

<a href="er.html" id="ack">Emergency Department Aftercare Instructions</a> is forthcoming in <a href="http://www.dreampoppress.net/" id="soon">Dream Pop Press</a>. <br><br>

<a href="transitive.html" id="ack">A Transitive Verb</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.cooprenner.com/2012/11/Trans.html" id="soon">elimae</a>.<br><br>

<a href="slammer.html" id="ack">Slammer</a> was originally published in <a href="https://thefemlitmagazine.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/slammer-stephanie-lane-sutton/" id="soon">The Fem</a>.</br><br>

<a href="loureed.html" id="ack">The Day Lou Reed Died</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.freezeraypoetry.com/stephanie-lane-sutton.html" id="soon">FreezeRay Poetry</a><br><br>

<a href="revocation.html" id="ack">Revocation</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.heartjournalonline.com/stephanie/" id="soon">HEArt Journal Online</a>.<br><br>

<a href="afterall.html" id="ack">After All</a> is forthcoming in <a href="http://www.littletell.org/" id="soon">littletell</a>.<br><br>

<a href="band.html" id="ack">In Middle School Band</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.moonsickmagazine.com/two-poems-by-stephanie-lane-sutton.html" id="soon">Moonsick Magazine</a><br><br>

<a href="eurydice.html" id="ack">Eurydice In Hell</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.thrushpoetryjournal.com/september-2014-stephanie-lane-sutton.html" id="soon">THRUSH Poetry Journal</a>. <br><br>

<a href="hysteria.html" id="ack">Hysteria</a> was originally published in <a href="http://www.tinderboxpoetry.com/hysteria" id="soon">Tinderbox Poetry Journal</a>.<br><br>





<center><a href=index.html>&#8962;</a></center>



</p>

<div id="left"><a href="er.html" class="previous round">&#8249;</a></div>

</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>



</div>

<div id="social-media-list">
  <div class="table">
    <ul id="social-media-list">

        <li>
            <a href=http://www.facebook.com/stephanielanesutton><img src=facebook.png></a> 
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=http://twitter.com/StephanieLaneS><img src=twitter.png></a> 
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=http://www.instagram.com/disorderliness/><img src=instagram.png></a> 
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href=http://github.com/wirginiavoolf><img src=github.png></a> 
        </li>

    </ul>





</div>




</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @media queries in CSS to change the layout of the page depending on the size of the screen.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    a { 
        font-size: 12px
    }
}
```

You basically just paste in all of your CSS code that you wish to change depending on screen size and just change the values; in this case, paste in the CSS referring to your links and just change the 'font-size: 12px' value.

This will allow you to resize the text when the end users browser screen is 480px or less. If you're wanting to do the same for tablet devices, use 768px.

Edit:

The values you're using for the font size are very small, 8px will be very small no matter what the screen size is. I tend to stick to 10-12px for standard text on mobile screens; dependig on what it is.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the link size problem. The small font sizes were grabbed from another post that said those were optimal for different screen sizes.